# How to do short form for number sequence using php

Tags: php, arrays

I got confused how to make short form for sequence number

i have an array elements like

```
$a = [2,3,4,7,8,9,10,11,13,15]
```

But i need output like

```
2-4, 7-11, 13, 15
```

Can you any body suggest how to do it in PHP?. Thank you

Comment: You can write a function that checks if the next one is > than the prev + 1..

Comment: sorry should be 7-11

Comment: So whats the schema behind that? it goes from 2-4 and then 7-10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function group_nums($array) { 
   $ret  = array(); 
   $temp = array(); 
   foreach($array as $val) { 
      if(next($array) == ($val + 1)) 
         $temp[] = $val; 
      else 
         if(count($temp) > 0) { 
            $temp[] = $val; 
            $ret[]  = $temp[0].'-'.end($temp); 
            $temp   = array(); 
         } 
         else 
            $ret[] = $val; 
   } 
   return $ret; 
}
```

[Test](http://ideone.com/fnlO0X)